# Generic function unable to compare between an array value and a standard value

Tags: c#, generics

Essentially, I'm trying to write a generic bruteforce getMax() method for a matrix.  Here is what I have:

```
 private T getMax <T>(T[,] matrix, uint rows, uint cols) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T max_val = matrix[0, 0];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            {
                if (matrix[row, col] > max_val)
                {
                    max_val = matrix[row, col];
                }
            }
        }
        return max_val;
    }
```

This won't compile, with the error `Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`.  I gave the IComparable directive, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  Why does this not work?

Comment: Rather than passing the rows and columns to the method you can just use `GetLength` to find the dimensions, unless you specifically want to search a subset of the matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use CompareTo() rather than the > operation.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.icomparable.aspx

In your case you'd put:

```
if (matrix[row, col].CompareTo(max_val) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `IComparable` means that it defines the `CompareTo` method, not that the `>` operator is defined.  You need to use:

```
if (matrix[row, col].CompareTo(max_val) > 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (matrix[row, col] > max_val)
```

Should be

```
if (matrix[row, col].CompareTo(max_val) > 0)
```

Since [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) provides only `CompareTo` not `>`.